Вывести уникальные значения из списка те которые попадают в диапазон n<10000
Есть список от сортированный по убыванию, как сделать так чтобы в диапазон до 10000 влезли только уникальные элементы списка,пока сделал, что он дублирует значения, если циклом while...
n = 10000

lst = [5240, 2130, 1200, 1000, 820, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 40, 20, 10]

for x in lst:
    while n>x:
        n-=x
        print(x, end = ' ')

выводит: 5240 2130 2130 400 40 40 10  
а надо чтобы выводил: 5240 2130 1200 1000 400 20 10

P.S. вот вроде так ну выводит все равно одинаковые.. 





Немного накосячил, простите.. сейчас видимо более менее понятно, что мне нужно.. получается надо чтобы проверялось список на уникальность, и если такого значения в списке нет, то он его считал и записывал, может быть возможно сделать через словарь. ??

while n>x: -> if n >= x:

Спасибо большое, работает)) !!! сейчас попробую вывести ключи словаря и выложу полный код, что я там натворил.0))

print(*(x for x in dict.fromkeys(lst) if x < 10000))

понял а вот звездочка и круглые скобки это список? или что это? как это работает)?

@AlexeySinitsky звездочка - это распаковка значений из генераторного выражения, которое в скобках

понял, удобно, как раз в коде его сделал...

Есть список:
lst = [5240, 2130, 1200, 1000, 820, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 40, 20, 10]

В этом списке УЖЕ уникальные значения! И все они меньше 10000!
Вот код, который исполняет буквально то, что Вы заказали:
n = 10000
lst = [5240, 2130, 2130, 1200, 1000, 820, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 40, 20, 10]
print(*sorted(set(filter(lambda x: x < 10000, lst)), reverse=True))

Вот результат:
5240 2130 1200 1000 820 600 500 400 300 200 100 40 20 10

Если бы в исходном списке были дубли, они были бы убраны.

да set filter lambda видел, ну еще не добрался.. ))

Исходная задача - задача о рюкзаке. Из списка весов нужно выбрать те, сумма которых не превысит заданного предела.

Список и словарь разные вещи! Как спросили, так и Вам и ответили. Программа должна быть другой в этом случае. Поскольку написали, что это дубликат, переписывать для Вас как бы не надо.

Вот как-то так получилось, видимо, не все гладко, ну соображал сам местами, подсмотрел только, как сортировать словарь по значению:
# вводим килограммы:
n = int(input())*1000

print(n)

things = {'карандаш': 20, 'зеркальце': 100, 'зонт': 500, 'рубашка': 300,
          'брюки': 1000, 'бумага': 200, 'молоток': 600, 'пила': 400, 'удочка': 1200,
          'расческа': 40, 'котелок': 820, 'палатка': 5240, 'брезент': 2130, 'спички': 10}

# тут подсмотрел как отсортировать словарь по убыванию значений,
# чтобы выводились ключи также по убыванию:
sorted_things = {keys:things[keys] for keys in sorted(things ,key=things.get, reverse=True)}

print(sorted_things)
#
# делаем значения:
lst = things.values()

# сортируем:
lst = sorted(lst)

# сортируем по убыванию:
lst = lst[::-1]
print(lst)

#
# #lst = [5240, 2130, 1200, 1000, 820, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 40, 20, 10]
#
arr = []

# делаем список значений, которые отсортированы по убыванию:
for x in lst:
    if n>=x:
        n-=x
        #print(x, end = ' ')
        arr.append(x)

print(arr)
#
# выводим словарь из списка значений:
out = [key for key, value in sorted_things.items() if value in arr]
#
# распаковываем его в строчку:
print(*out)


Добавьте в вопрос формулировку решаемой задачи.

Задачу в вопросе надо формулировать полностью:
things = {'карандаш': 20, 'зеркальце': 100, 'зонт': 500, 'рубашка': 300,
          'брюки': 1000, 'бумага': 200, 'молоток': 600, 'пила': 400, 'удочка': 1200,
          'расческа': 40, 'котелок': 820, 'палатка': 5240, 'брезент': 2130, 'спички': 10}

lst = sorted(((v, k) for k, v in things.items()), reverse=True)

n = int(input()) * 1000
for w, t in lst:
    if n >= w:
        n -= w
        print(t, end=' ')
print()


$ echo 10 | python rucksack.py
палатка брезент удочка брюки пила карандаш спички


